# EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt error while trying to decrypt data encrypted with key and IV

Tags: openssl, encryption-asymmetric

Key and IV are generated with EVP_SealInit and aes-256-cbc. Encrypts the key with public key where the encrypted key and iv is further used to encrypt the data. The key needs to be decrypted with private key and the decrypted key is used along with iv to decrypt the data back to plaintext. I'm able decrypt the key with RSA private key but it is failing to decrypt the data further (Err: EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt).

Comment: Neither crystal balls nor ESP are good debuggers.  Post your code.  Telling us about your code is useless.  The only answer you can get is:  You wrote bad code - go fix it.

Comment: You are supposed to use EVP_OpenInit/EVP_OpenUpdate/EVP_OpenFinal to decrypt data encrypted with EVP_SealInit/EVP_SealUpdate/EVP_SealFinal.